# Can't build react native project in Xcode

Tags: ios, react-native

I try to build a "fresh" react-native project in Xcode and run it on the phone but it says `library not found for -lDoubleConversion`.

When I build it with `npx react-native run-ios` it runs fine in the simulator.

What am I missing? I found on the net that I am not the only one with this issue but I can't find the solution.

I spent already two days trying to find some solution and I have to say that I slowly stop believing that people are using react to build ios applications :-(

Edit:
After several days of investigation, I still can't build it. I have found similar issues on the web and many hints were about the installation of third-party libraries. I tried to run this script:

`cd node_modules/react-native/scripts && ./ios-install-third-party.sh && cd ../../../`. But with an error:

`./ios-install-third-party.sh 
Unpacking /Users/mastalir/Library/Caches/com.facebook.ReactNativeBuild/glog-0.3.5.tar.gz...
./ios-install-third-party.sh: line 66: ./ios-configure-glog.sh: No such file or directory`

Comment: Did you run pod install ?

Comment: Hello, yes i did.

Comment: But i am not sure if it compiles third party libs correctly. Where should i found the compiled lib? What is confusing to me that xcode is looking for the library in this directory: `/Users/mastalir/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FirstAppPokus-cbuqwrugcrxcpsfzpmswqpkonnnp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DoubleConversion'` but it contains just the corrupted App file and no libs

Answer (score 6):

Finaly a made it working. It was a quite silly issue. I have been opening the .xcodeproj but it is needed to open .xcworkspace file in Xcode.
Everything is working now in Xcode.

Comment: After a day of searching. I can't believe it was so simple.

Answer (score 0):

please add below pods i your `Podfile`.

```
pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
 pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
 pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
```

goto ios folder and run `pod install`,

hope this works for you.

Comment: Hello, I tried `pod install` many times but it doesn't help. In my Podfile i can see all of these pods already. When I run pod install it says `Pod installation complete! There are 28 dependencies from the Podfile and 26 total pods installed.` Isn't it that the problem that 26 is installed but should be 28?