# React Native - XCodeBuild - Fatal Error: Module Map File

Tags: react-native, xcodebuild

I'm trying to build an inherited React Native app.

Everytime I build via xcodebuild I get the following error:

```
fatal error: module map file 
'/Users/xcodeclub/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-fpunvqnzmyqummgfroiwvewvqwdb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/appname/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/WCPhotoManipulator/WCPhotoManipulator.modulemap'
not found
```

iOS version in XCode is: 12.0

PodFile has the following in:

```
platform :ios, '12.0'
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing derived data ?

Comment: Try clearing derived data https://programmingwithswift.com/delete-derived-data-xcode/

Comment: yes I've tried to delete that, usually running on a GitHub action so assume it's clean everytime.

Comment: cleaning derived didn't work for me. Is there another solution???

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue, looks like it was this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60151515/7583100

There's an xcodeproj file for your main project, and an xcworkspace that includes all the native libraries you need.  Opening the xcworkspace and building that will build the modules you're looking for